# discord.js say command actually says "say"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've never had a problem with the say command until I start using modules and cleaned up my code but since I have few my commands have bugged. I'm trying to figure out why it is saying the command.

```
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {

    case "say":
      bot.commands.get("say").execute(message, args);
      break;
```

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "say",
  description: "Show's avatar",
 async execute(message, args){

    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    message.channel.send(`${sayMessage} - ${message.author}`);
  }
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is doing exactly what you programmed it to, be it not intended.

```js
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" "); // args = ['say', 'Hello', 'World']

bot.commands.get("say").execute(message, args); // Passing in the entire args array

const sayMessage = args.join(" "); // sayMessage = 'say Hello World'
```

One solution of many:

```js
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
const command = args.splice(0, 1); // args now only contains the arguments

switch (command) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help from you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this is using the anidiots guidebot boiler plate i highly recommend using it to help you better understand incorporating a command handler into your discord bot.

your going to want to download the repo from here https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/guidebot/

1. extract it
2. run npm install
3. in the commands folder add say.js using the code below this is how to properly execute what your trying todo
4. by default the prefix is ~ to change it in discord chat run ~conf edit prefix  Example: ~conf edit prefix !
5. run !say hello world

````
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => { 
    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send(sayMessage + ' - ' + message.author)
  };

  exports.conf = {
    enabled: true,
    guildOnly: false,
    aliases: [],
    permLevel: "User"
  };

  exports.help = {
    name: "say",
    category: "Miscelaneous",
    description: "say command",
    usage: "say"
  };```
````

Comment: ```const args = message.content.slice(settings.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    
        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: this is the most common fix for your issue though. you can just shift the first argument out of the array which in your case will always be the command name. 

```const args = message.content.slice(settings.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();```