# Discord command not doing what I want it to do - discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here is my code, if I do !say hi, the bot would delete my message and write "say hi" and I don't know how to fix it

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("!say")) {
        if (message.deletable) { 
            message.delete();
        }
        if (args.length < 1) {
            return message.reply("Nothing to say").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        }
        message.channel.send(args.join(" "));
    }
```

Comment: How is `args` assigned? If the bot says "say hi" then `args` obviously must have been `["say", "hi"]`, so whatever method was used to create it is clearly incorrect.

Comment: `let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");`

Comment: Use `.slice(1)` to chop off the first argument, which will be the command itself. Then you'll only have the arguments which aren't the command itself.

Comment: So where would I put that?

Comment: Put it wherever it makes the most sense. Where do you want all of the arguments excluding the command part? Only in the say command? Everywhere? Just use `args.slice(1)` where you don't want the command part.

Comment: I don't know where to put it

Comment: Or can someone give me a code that works?

Comment: Programming isn't about finding pieces of code that do things and putting them in the right order. I suggest you take some time to learn the basics of JavaScript so that you understand the *why* of working code and where to put it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js say command actually says "say"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59816652/discord-js-say-command-actually-says-say)

Comment: It is very clear to Nek how you define `args` most likely a problem in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the snipped below you just had too cut the first part off, as the comments already stated. If you type "!say hi" the args variable looks like this ["!say","hi"] with args.slice(1) you remove the first part, so you remove the "!say" and "hi" is the only argument left in args. Then you can just send the message to the channle with the remaining arguments.

```
if (message.content.startsWith("!say")) {
        if (message.deletable) { 
            message.delete();
        }
        if (args.length < 1) {
            return message.reply("Nothing to say").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        }
        message.channel.send(args.slice(1).join(" "));
    }
```

Sry for my bad english :D